# How to move absolutely position elements depending on screen size in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi I am building a magnetic poetry game where you drag words together to form some phrases.  I am Using jqueryui draggable and droppable with absolute positioned divs.

http://test-magnets.meteor.com/

I am also trying to make the game responsive as much as possible.  I have a bank of words to the right of the fridge that have a class "not-in-play"  once you drop on the fridge that class is removed.  So when the screen size is smaller i just want to move the magnets that have the class "not-in-play".

i was thinking something like this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var screenwidth = $(window).width()
    if (screenwidth <= 800) {
     $('magnet.not-in-play').each(function(){  
      var currentPosLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'));
      $(this).css('left', (currentPosLeft - 1000) + 'px');
     }); 
    } 
  });
```

I can get an alert to fire inside the if block but any css i try is not working.  It works in the console fine hence my confusion.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

this seems to work fine in a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ff0ynexc/
just not in my app

-John

Comment: Have you thought about css media queries?

Comment: I am using Less,  is there away to get the current position value and run a calculation to move each div the same distance?  and throw that in a media query?  that would be ideal

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do something with "dynamic" widths like the jquery concept in you question, but if you just wanted to set static values based on different viewport widths it works well. It just depends on what your needs are - it may or may not work for you for what you are doing. There _is_ `calc()` which has [decent support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: yeah was thinking of using calc() but need a way to grab the current left position of each div then do some math on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `-=` will not work (you're setting the properties directly), instead do something like

```
var currentPosLeft = parseInt($('.magnet.not-in-play').css('left'));
$('.magnet.not-in-play').css('left', (currentPosLeft - 600) + 'px');
```

(You'll probably have to do that in a loop)

Comment: so something like

  $(document).ready(function() {

        var screenwidth = $(window).width()
        if (screenwidth <= 800) {

         $('magnet.not-in-play').each(function(){  
        var currentPosLeft = parseInt($('this').css('left'));
        $('this').css('left', (currentPosLeft - 1000) + 'px');
        }); 
        }
});

Comment: yeah. if they all have the same value for left it might work without the loop. no ticks around the `this` though, it's a variable, not a string

Comment: oops good catch.  still not working but appreciate your help.

Comment: Your way works in my fiddle marking it correct--thanks

Comment: we would probably need more code then if you want help with that ;)